# IN clause for Oracle Prepared Statement in Python cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, prepared-statement, cx-oracle

I'd like to use the IN clause with a prepared Oracle statement using cx_Oracle in Python.

E.g. query - `select name from employee where id in ('101', '102', '103')`

On python side, I have a list `[101, 102, 103]` which I converted to a string like this `('101', '102', '103')` and used the following code in python -

```
import cx_Oracle
ids = [101, 102, 103]
ALL_IDS = "('{0}')".format("','".join(map(str, ids)))
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'pass', 'schema')
cursor = conn.cursor()
results = cursor.execute('select name from employee where id in :id_list', id_list=ALL_IDS)
names = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
rows = results.fetchall()
```

This doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This concept is not supported by Oracle -- and you are definitely not the first person to try this approach either! You must either:

- create separate bind variables for each in value -- something that is fairly easy and straightforward to do in Python
- create a subquery using the cast operator on Oracle types as is shown in this post: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:210612357425
- use a stored procedure to accept the array and perform multiple queries directly within PL/SQL
- or do something else entirely!

Comment: cx_Oracle doc on this is in [Binding Multiple Values to a SQL WHERE IN Clause](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Just transform your list into a tuple and format the sql string with it

```
ids = [101, 102, 103]
param = tuple(ids)
results = cursor.execute("select name from employee where id IN {}".format(param))
```

Answer (score -1):

Otra opción es dar formato a una cadena con la consulta.

```
import cx_Oracle
ids = [101, 102, 103]
ALL_IDS = "('{0}')".format("','".join(map(str, ids)))
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'pass', 'schema')
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = """
select name from employee where id in ('{}')
""".format("','".join(map(str, ids)))

results = cursor.execute(query)
names = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
rows = results.fetchall()
```

Comment: This can be a BIG security hole if your data is not sanitized.  Generally it is mandatory to use bind variables, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause.  Bind variables can also improve scalability and performance, though if a query isn't executed much, or the number of variables changes a lot, the scalability benefit may be minimal.

Answer (score -3):

Since you created the string, you're almost there. This should work:

```
results = cursor.execute('select name from employee where id in ' + ALL_IDS)
```

Comment: Unless you whitelist and validate all values, this is a major security risk.