# How to pass list values to SQL Select query?

Tags: python, oracle, list, parameter-passing, cx-oracle

SQL query:

```
Select *
from table_name 
where ID in (123) 
  and date in (Select max(date) 
               from table_name 
               where ID in (123))
```

I want to pass below mentioned list values one at time in above SQL query and collect results for each ID in list
Package: cx_Oracle

My try:

```
import cx_oracle
List= {123, 234,345,....}
List1 = []
query = " Select * from table_name where ID in (%s) 
     and date in (Select max(date) from table_name where ID in (%s))"

for j in List:
    cursor1 = db_ora.cursor()
    tb = cursor1.execute(query, params= List )
    for i in tb:
        List1.append(i)
```

Thank you in advance, let me know if you need more details from my side

Comment: I don't know Python, but in SQL `(123, 234, 345)` refers to three separate values, not one. If you can bind to a collection that would be different (a `table()` expression or `member of`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IN clause for Oracle Prepared Statement in Python cx\_Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954293/in-clause-for-oracle-prepared-statement-in-python-cx-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it similar to your original code, you can use string formatting

### Python 2

```
import cx_oracle
List= [123, 234,345,....]
List1 = []
masterQuery = " Select * from table_name where ID in (%s) 
     and date in (Select max(date) from table_name where ID in (%s))"

for j in List:
    cursor1 = db_ora.cursor()
    newQuery = masterQuery % (j, j)
    tb = cursor1.execute(newQuery)
    for i in tb:
        List1.append(i)
```

### Python 3

```
import cx_oracle
List= [123, 234,345,....]
List1 = []
masterQuery = " Select * from table_name where ID in {} 
     and date in (Select max(date) from table_name where ID in {})"

for j in List:
    cursor1 = db_ora.cursor()
    newQuery = masterQuery.format(j, j)
    tb = cursor1.execute(newQuery)
    for i in tb:
        List1.append(i)
```

Comment: really??  this is pretty much begging for an SQL injection attack!

Comment: In this case it looks like this person is just using hard coded values from their own list, so I don't see where any injection would occur. Of course if you were making this into a user facing application this would be vulnerable, but this case seems pretty safe.

Comment: For some generic WHERE IN bind solutions see https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#sqlwherein (and rewrite the examples in Python)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Oracle won't accept such a list as a valid parameter. Either store that list of values into a separate table and use it as a source for your query, such as

```
and t.date in (select max(t1.date) from table_name t1
               where t1.id in (select st.id from some_table st)
              )
```

or, if possible, split that comma-separated-values string into rows, e.g.

```
and t.date in (select max(t1.date) from table_name t1
               where t1.id in (select regexp_substr(%s, '[^,]+', 1, level) 
                               from dual
                               connect by level <= regexp_count(%s, ',') + 1
                              )
              )
```

Also, I'd suggest you to precede column names with table aliases to avoid possible confusion.

Comment: the postgresql database connector uses `tuple`s for `IN` lists.  i.e. `cur.execute("SELECT 1 IN %s", [(1,2,3)])` will give `TRUE` back

Comment: I thought I saw "Oracle" tag here, not "Postgresql", @Sam. But OK, thank you for the comment, no problem :)

Comment: yup, don't have an oracle database here!  hence not posting a real answer…

Comment: Thank you guys, appreciated your help