# Python cx_Oracle - how to bind array to cursor.execute()

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I have following SQL

```
select * from my_table
where my_param in :params
```

How do I bind python list or another array to cx_Oracle cursor execute expression?

This does not work

```
cursor.execute(my_sql, {'params': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: I found at least one duplicate after all, but still think, that would be good to receive actual answers and left this as is for better search. There it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954293/in-clause-for-oracle-prepared-statement-in-python-cx-oracle

Comment: In case anyone finds this question and want to bind an array of values for insert, see the cx_Oracle example https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/BindInsert.py.

Answer (score 2):

After searching around for a long time, I found this solution most elegant for me to pass a list to a oracle sql statement.

It requires that you can create new types within the database.

**create a nested table type in the database**

```sql
create type t_id_tab as table of number;
```

Please note that in oracle 11 this must be done on schema level and not within a package. Otherwise our statement (see next step) will not work.

**the python script**

With cx_Oracle one can use the object api to create a new object of custom types. This object can than be passed to the query.

```
import cx_Oracle


db = cx_Oracle.connect("my_user", "my_password", "<host>:<port>/<sid>")
cursor = db.cursor()

id_list_type = db.gettype("t_id_tab")
id_list = id_list_type.newobject([1, 2, 3, 4])

cursor.execute("select * from my_table where my_param in (select column_value from table (:id_values))", id_values=id_list)
```

**Untested version for oracle 12 onwards**

It is said,that from oracle12 onwards the same sql syntax as above works also for associative arrays. I cannot test it. But if  this is right, this should work without creating a custom collection type;

```
import cx_Oracle


db = cx_Oracle.connect("my_user", "my_password", "<host>:<port>/<sid>")
cursor = db.cursor()

id_list = cursor.arrayvar(cx_Oracle.NUMBER, [1, 2, 3, 4])

cursor.execute("select * from my_table where my_param in (select column_value from table (:id_values))", id_values=id_list)
```